# How to remove a ping command from Discord bot

Tags: discord.js

Just recently I’ve decided to work on a discord bot but I seem to be having trouble with a command in particular. I’m unsure with how to stop the bot from pinging a specific person when responding.
Here is the code :

```
bot.on(‘message’, msg=>{

    if(msg.content === “Hello!”);

       msg.reply(“Hello there!”);

    }

})
```

I’ve even attempted adding “msg.channel.send”just before it’s response.
Anyone know what to do? I’d really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `send()` instead of `reply()` since `reply()` will mention the person that ran the command.

```js
bot.on('message', msg=>{

    if(msg.content === 'Hello!');

       msg.channel.send('Hello there!');

    }

})
```

Also, you should not be using those fancy quotation marks `“` `”`. Use single `'` or double `"` quotation marks instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! You were very helpful, I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome, if an answer solves your question then accept it using the tick mark next to it to let others know your question has been answered and also to show what worked